# unexpected &nbsp; added in HTML at each update

Tags: html-editor

I'm using the last update of Wordpress and I'm not using Tiny MCE.

I found many posts about it, but each time it was a bug from a previous version (closed) or linked to Tiny MCE.

I modify my pages only in HTML because I'm using complicated CSS and DIVs.

Each time I update my code lots of `$nbsp;` are added everywhere even if I remove every spaces between my tags and even at the begining. Here is an example :

**before** *(it's the beginning of the page, there's no space or line before `<aside>`)*:

```
<aside class="alignleft" style="width: 375px;">[...]</aside><section>[...]
```

**after**:

```
$nbsp;

<aside class="alignleft" style="width: 375px;">[...]</aside>

$nbsp;

<section>[...]
```

And next update each `&nbsp;` is duplicated, and next ones again (2,4,8,16...)

I tried to add this to function.php, and it didn't work:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update is out today: wordpress 3.4 and this bug is corrected!